# Javascript - call json number value

Tags: javascript, json, postgresql

I have a javascript function calling from a Postgresql database. In my database i have columns that are numbers. I am using the database to return aviation fuel data. So the column names are distance in KM and the rows are the amount of fuel used.

```
Example Database:

CODE |   125 | 150  |   200 | 250 |  3000 |

141  |  1289 | 2754 |  3874 | 5258 | 6600 |
```

My javascript function return this

using this:
`console.log((fuelUsed.rows[0]));`

I get this:
`{ '125': '1289' }`

How do I return: `1289`

Comment: Looks Like Key Value pairs try this .

fuelUsed.rows['125']
or fuelUsed[125] 
or fuelUsed.125 
or fuelUsed.rows[0].'125'

I would need to see more script to test it .

Comment: @jonoJames I think it would be on the lines of console.log(fuelUsed.rows[0].'125') but that doesn't. its have a problem referencing 125. i need the .rows[0]

Comment: `const [dist, fuel] = Object.entries(fuelUsed.rows[0])[0];`

Comment: ~~@ChrisG The response is an object, variable assignment unpacking requires an iterable to unpack.~~ Apologies, I was incorrect.

Comment: @Matthias `Object.entries()` returns an array. Try my suggestion for yourself and you'll find it works perfectly fine.

Comment: This sounds like an issue with your SQL. Could you update question with the SQL query you're making and what postgres library you're using?

Comment: @Chris G thanks thats worked. Thanks, really appreciate it.

Comment: The bigger question here is if that DB structure is suitable for the kind of data it stores. Columns shouldn't have arbitrary names; a better way to store that data is to put the distance and fuel in a row where the columns are named `distance` and `fuel`. OTOH, if a specific column is requested, then the code knows the column name i.e. required object key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One line solutions:

```js
const fuelUsed = { // test data
  rows: [{"CODE": 141}, {"125": 1289 }, {"150": 2754}, {"200": 3874}, {"250": 5258}, {"3000": 6600}] 
};

// Solution 1: for 1 value:
function getValue(row) {
  return row[Object.keys(row)[0]];
}

console.log(getValue(fuelUsed.rows[1])); // returns 1289 

// For all array
let values = fuelUsed.rows.map(row => row[Object.keys(row)[0]]);

console.log(values) // [141, 1289, 2754, 3874, 5258, 6600]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getValue(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        return obj[key]
    }
}
console.log(getValue(fuelUsed.rows[0]))
```

See if this does the trick

Answer (score 0):

Without the use of the dot notation ...

```
let  js = [{'212':'4454'},{'2':'21'},{'1':'223'}];

      console.log(js[0]['212']);
```